# Função válida para todas páginas

Tags: php, htaccess

É possível definir uma função para todas as páginas sem usar `include()` em todas elas?

- Ex: Tenho um diretório sigiloso `../seg/staff/login/` e quero definir que usuário com nível de permissão menor que 3 não pode acessa-los.

Poderia criar um arquivo `seg.php`:

```
if($nivel < 3){
    echo ("Você não possui permissão para isto.");
}
```

E chamá-lo nos demais com `include("seg.php")`.

Agora digamos que tenho 70 páginas. Existe alguma possibilidade de eu definir isto em algum `.htacess` ou outro sem precisar colocar `require("")`, `include("")`, etc. em todos os arquivos?

Comment: Eu vejo muita gente sofrendo para fazer coisas básicas por não ter conhecimento ou mesmo por não se interessar em utilizar algum `framework` de desenvolvimento, gente, não precisamos sofrer com desenvolvimento de coisas básicas na unha, já tem muita gente trabalhando pra deixar isso pronto pra nós, sugiro que dê uma olhada no `Laravel`, ou qualquer outro Framework de desenvolvimento em `PHP`...vc vai ter esse, e milhares de outros problemas resolvidos facilmente...

Comment: @KennyRafael Blz realmente nunca fui atrás de **framework** vou procurar dar uma olhada sobre o mesmo. Obrigado pelo **feedback**

Comment: Na melhor das situações, se você tem apenas arquivos PHP no diretorio, isso é apenas e somente PHP puro, então irá ter apenas um `<?php` por arquivo, dessa forma poderá usar o seu Editor/IDE substituir todos os `<?php` por `<?php include("seg.php");`, dessa forma todos os arquivos no diretorio terá o `include("seg.php")`. Agora, se você junta PHP com HTML e tem mais de um possivelmente terá mais de um `<?php`, então terá problema.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a directiva "auto_prepend_file" do PHP, isso vai incluir sua lógica em todas as páginas.

Comment: Essa diretiva vai onde? poderia dar um exemplo.

Comment: @rray pode ser no .htaccess
# é só colocar aqui o caminho do seu script a ser incluído na suas páginas
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

php_value auto_prepend_file "/caminho-do-script/seu-script.php"